# How do I run Google Chrome remotely on X windows

Tags: google-chrome, x11

I am wondering how I run Google Chrome remotely on Linux ?

With Firefox I can invoke :

```
firefox --display 192.168.0.5:0.0
```

How do I do the same with Chrome ?

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried:

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.0.5:0.0
```

just before starting Chrome?

Comment: Pleasure. Feel free to mark answers as useful using 'up' arrow at the left, and/or mark answers as "accepted" if you like :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to direct any GUI based application to your local setup, You can do export `DISPLAY="Your_Local_IP":0.0` on the machine hosting application. then launch the application, for example chrome in your case, so just run `google-chrome` and the display would be directed to your local machine.

Comment: I needed to do a "google-chrome --disable-gpu" to get things working. Also I think the easiest way of securely forwarding X is just "ssh -X", which should automatically setup the DISPLAY environment variable correctly.